# Controlling keyboard position in QTextEdit

Tags: qt

Is there any way to control the keyboard cursor in QTextEdit? For instance move the cursor one line up, or two positions back. I have looked at the QCursor class, but is this only for the mouse cursor? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QTextCursor::movePosition(MoveOperation operation, MoveMode mode=MoveAnchor, int n=1)
```

This method allows you to move the cursor in [**various ways**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtextcursor.html#MoveOperation-enum), such as one word to the right or up one line.

You can use it like this:

```
QTextCursor c = textEdit->textCursor();
c.movePosition(QTextCursor::Up);
textEdit->setTextCursor(c);
```

If you need to select some text, not just move the cursor, specify the [**`MoveMode`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtextcursor.html#MoveMode-enum) as KeepAnchor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html#moveCursor